# Explain why $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a} = |a^2|$

Tags: vectors

Can somebody explain why:

$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a} = |a^2|$

I know that using the dot product $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a} = |a|\cdot |a|\cdot \cos \theta$

What happens to $\cos \theta$

Comment: Do you know what $\theta$ *means*?

Comment: @T.Bongers the angle between the vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta$ is the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec a$, i.e. $\theta=0$. Since $\cos(0)=1$, you get your result.